# global mouse hook in console application

Tags: c#, winapi, hook, pinvoke

I want to get acquainted with WinAPI in C#.

I need to write a global mouse hook in the console application. I found the code that does this job. But I have a console application, and I shouldn't use Application.Run () from Windows.Forms.

I need to forward messages about the coordinates of the mouse from winAPI directly to the console window without winForms. How can i do this?

```
class InterceptMouse
{
    private static LowLevelMouseProc _proc = HookCallback;

    private static IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;

    public static void Main()
    {
        _hookID = SetHook(_proc);

        Application.Run();

        UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);
    }

    private static IntPtr SetHook(LowLevelMouseProc proc)
    {
        using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
        using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)

        {
            return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, proc,

                GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0);
        }
    }

    private delegate IntPtr LowLevelMouseProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    private static IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (nCode >= 0 && MouseMessages.WM_MOUSEMOVE == (MouseMessages)wParam)
        {
            MSLLHOOKSTRUCT hookStruct = (MSLLHOOKSTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(MSLLHOOKSTRUCT));
            Console.WriteLine(hookStruct.pt.x + ", " + hookStruct.pt.y);
        }

        return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }

    private const int WH_MOUSE_LL = 14;

    private enum MouseMessages
    {
        WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201,
        WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202,
        WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x0200,
        WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x020A,
        WM_RBUTTONDOWN = 0x0204,
        WM_RBUTTONUP = 0x0205
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]

    private struct POINT
    {
        public int x;
        public int y;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]

    private struct MSLLHOOKSTRUCT
    {
        public POINT pt;
        public uint mouseData;
        public uint flags;
        public uint time;
        public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]

    private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, LowLevelMouseProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]

    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]

    private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);


    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]

    private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]

    private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);
}
```

Comment: The `Application.Run` call sets up the message pump for the application.

Comment: The question is decided by me here: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/830231/global-mouse-hook-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8/830344#830344

Answer (score 0):

Add system.windows.forms as a reference to your project.

using System.Windows.Forms;

It should be work then.